# Using regex in XSLT 1.0 (exslt)

Tags: xml, xslt, nokogiri, exslt

I have to use a regular expression to remove the useless text from a string and be able to build the correct one from it. The problem is that I don't seem to make EXLT's `regex:match` function work.

The regular expression I need to match the strings to is `/(\d{4})-0*(\d{0,4})/` (4 numbers followed by a dash (-), followed by as many zeros as it may have, followed by up to 4 numbers). Then finally I need to grab the first 4 numbers, replace the dash with a colon, and remove all the zeros.

Some input examples could be `somethingCool_SFS2000-120#somethingEle`, `uselessText1995-0001234moreNon-sense`, `3500-0950blabl!abla`.
The output for these examples should be `2000:120`, `1995:1234` and `3500:950`

I tried using a JS function, but Nokogiri complained. Same issue for EXSLT `regex:match` function. What is really weird is that in another file I used EXSLT's `string:encode-uri` without any issues.

Worst case scenario I'll write a recursive function to check for every character of the string to build the correct one, but I think there should be an easier way.

This is my xslt file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  xmlns:regexp="http://exslt.org/regular-expressions">

  <xsl:template match="metadata-entry">
    <xsl:variable name="chunks" select="regexp:match(@value, '/(\d{4})-0*(\d{0,4})/')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="prettyName">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat($chunks[2], ':' , $chunks[3])" />
    </xsl:variable>
      <div class="x-paragraph">
        <xsl:value-of select="$prettySfsName"/>
      </div>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And this is the other file where I used EXSLT string function the same way, but this time it actually works fine

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings">
  <xsl:template match="authors">

    <xsl:variable name="authorUrl" select="concat('/b/search?q=', str:encode-uri(@full-name, 'true', 'UTF-8' ))"/>
    
    <a href='{$authorUrl}'>
      <xsl:value-of select="@full-name" />
    </a>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by  *"I don't seem to make EXLT's `regex:match` function work"*. Does the processor you use support this function or not? The fact that it supports another extension function is irrelevant.

Comment: What does `<xsl:value-of select="function-available('regexp:match')"/>` (with the namespace `xmlns:regexp="http://exslt.org/regular-expressions"` declared in the XSLT code) output with your XSLT processor?

Comment: @michael.hor257k I'm trying to use the extension from EXSLT. I already have the corresponding namespace declared.

Comment: @MartinHonnen it returns false..., I'll edit the question with my full xslt file so u have more context

Comment: Yes, I understand you are trying to use an EXSLT extension function. You seem to believe that if your processor supports one EXSLT function, it must support all of them. That is not so - and if the test suggested by Martin Honnen returns false, then the function is not supported (and you should be getting an error message telling you this).

Comment: @michael.hor257 ok great then, now at least I know why. Documentation for these functions is not the best. In both cases the "official documentation" says that the supported processors are the same, but apparently not

Comment: You cannot rely on the ancient documentation on EXSLT site to reflect the current state of (also ancient) processors. You need to consult the documentation of your own processor or query it yourself.